# Bluetooth not working (no adapters found) - ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO - AX200 - iwlwifi works however

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, 20.04, 19.10

My PC:

```
{21:26}~ ➭ uname -a
Linux trunk3 5.3.0-40-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 31 20:24:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

{21:27}~ ➭ inxi -Fz
System:    Host: trunk3 Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.16.5 Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO (WI-FI) v: Rev X.0x serial: <filter> 
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 0803 date: 08/01/2019 
CPU:       Topology: 12-Core model: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
[...]
Network:   Device-1: Realtek driver: N/A 
           Device-2: Intel I211 Gigabit Network driver: igb 
           IF: enp5s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-3: Intel driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp6s0 state: up mac: <filter>
```

Status: WiFi is working (currently connected over wifi only)

Problem: Bluetooth reports "no adapters found".

What I tried:

```
{21:35}~ ➭ lspci | grep Net
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)

{21:35}~ ➭ modprobe -c | grep 2723
alias pci:v00008086d00002723sv*sd00000080bc*sc*i* iwlwifi
[...]

{21:37}~ ➭ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.304538] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.329819] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    3.329823] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.329824] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.330042] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.346453] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.357723] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.358098] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.505318] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: base HW address: dc:71:96:88:62:83
[    3.519954] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.522491] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.670133] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    8.219398] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Unhandled alg: 0x707
```

and also

```
{21:41}~ ➭ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# quit

{21:42}~ ➭ ll /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
insgesamt 748K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K Jan 31 19:32 ath3k.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13K Jan 31 19:32 bcm203x.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26K Jan 31 19:32 bfusb.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16K Jan 31 19:32 bluecard_cs.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20K Jan 31 19:32 bpa10x.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15K Jan 31 19:32 bt3c_cs.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16K Jan 31 19:32 btbcm.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24K Jan 31 19:32 btintel.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36K Jan 31 19:32 btmrvl.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  42K Jan 31 19:32 btmrvl_sdio.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24K Jan 31 19:32 btmtksdio.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6,5K Jan 31 19:32 btmtkuart.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23K Jan 31 19:32 btqca.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8,5K Jan 31 19:32 btrsi.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21K Jan 31 19:32 btrtl.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16K Jan 31 19:32 btsdio.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  83K Jan 31 19:32 btusb.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13K Jan 31 19:32 btwilink.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14K Jan 31 19:32 dtl1_cs.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26K Jan 31 19:32 hci_nokia.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233K Jan 31 19:32 hci_uart.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14K Jan 31 19:32 hci_vhci.ko
```

No wireless dongles are attached via USB:

```
{22:11}~ ➭ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 04a9:176b Canon, Inc. PIXMA MX920 Series
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 046d:c051 Logitech, Inc. G3 (MX518) Optical Mouse
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 05af:0802 Jing-Mold Enterprise Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05e3:0732 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:18f3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 28de:1142 Valve Software Wireless Steam Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also installed bluez-tools and bluez-tests, but do not currently know how to use them or whether they are useful. Bluetooth is set to enabled in the BIOS/UEFI.

```
{21:52}~ ➭ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.311096] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.311124] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.311126] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.311128] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.311129] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.272042] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.272044] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.272049] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.330777] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[    5.331075] Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout
```

Any hints on further debugging?

**Update 2020-05-31**

I also installed kubuntu 20.04 LTS, with no change:

```
{16:26}~ ➭ uname -a
Linux trunk3 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

{16:26}~ ➭ inxi -Fz
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-33-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO (WI-FI) v: Rev X.0x serial: <filter>
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 0803 date: 08/01/2019
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE driver: r8169
           IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel I211 Gigabit Network driver: igb 
           IF: enp5s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           Device-3: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp6s0 state: down mac: <filter>
```

**Update 2020-09-18**

Reading the answer from Dorian Gaensslen below, I tried the following:

```
{9:29}~ ➭ lsmod | grep btusb
btusb                  57344  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
bluetooth             581632  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
{9:31}~ ➭ sudo rmmod btusb
{9:32}~ ➭ lsmod | grep btusb
{22:29}~ ➭ sudo modprobe btusb
[sudo] Passwort für kayd: 
{22:57}~ ➭ lsmod | grep btusb                              
btusb                  57344  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
bluetooth             581632  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
{22:57}~ ➭ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller DC:71:96:88:62:87 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device BC:30:7D:0E:05:25 Broadcom
[CHG] Device BC:30:7D:0E:05:25 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device BC:30:7D:0E:05:25 Connected: no
[NEW] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 h.ear (MDR-100ABN)
[CHG] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 10:4F:A8:B4:05:B6 Paired: yes
[h.ear (MDR-100ABN)]#
```

It worked. I have not been able to find out yet why.
However, although it does not look like it would be permanent, but it is a permanent fix for me, i.e. it is still working after a reboot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Try the 5.5 kernel. There should be a fix for this `version information` error.

Comment: I'm having second thoughts about installing an upstream kernel because [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds] tells me that because of the proprietary nvidia drivers it may fail to boot. (I am missing the grub boot menu I used to have earlier.)

Comment: Well, Nvidia drivers won't work, but BT may work. Remove the Nvidia drivers and try if this is the case. If BT work, it's possible to backport the fix to 5.3.

Comment: I believe this is your bluetooth device: `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp.`

Comment: @chili555: not sure, as [https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/products/docs/wireless/wi-fi-6-ax200-module-brief.html] seems to imply that this chip(set) contains both Wifi plus Bluetooth.

Comment: The device is `8087:0029`. It is supported by kernel. But the fix is needed.

Comment: "this chip(set) contains both Wifi plus Bluetooth" Quite correct; however, the bluetooth part appears as USB and the wifi part appears as PCI.

Comment: Thanks @chili555, I didn't know this was even possible. You never stop learning...

Comment: @kay_D, did you solve this problem? I am facing the same problem right now.

Comment: I did not have a try yet, as I am dependent on a "productive" environment (working from home), and am afraid to uninstall drivers that are required (I had serious gfx problems when I set up my system and are glad that it works right now). So I am inclined to wait until ubuntu 20.4 or for a kernel that will not require uninstalling the nv drivers.

Comment: I now installed kubuntu 20.04 (mainly only because of this issue), presuming it would be using the 5.5 kernel, but `uname -a` now gives `Linux trunk3 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Bad Luck.

Comment: `dmesg | grep -i blue` still says `hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)` like with 19.10. I hope the fix will be backported to 20.04 LTS.

Comment: having same issues, although I'm not getting this error message: `hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)` for `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: @Junaid what is the difference in output to mine when you use e.g `lsusb | grep 8087` or  `dmesg | grep -i blue`?

Comment: @kay_D `lsusb | grep 8087` output is `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp.`

Comment: @kay_D for `dmesg | grep -i blue` I was getting the same logs as you were except the last two lines `[    5.330777] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[    5.331075] Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout`

Comment: but today I checked again, I'm not getting any Bluetooth logs at all, the command `dmesg | grep -i blue` just exits with status code 1 since it doesn't find anything

Comment: I don't see `rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
` bluetooth here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same:

Can you try the following?

```
sudo rmmod btusb
```

and then

```
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Sorry had a typo. Try `modprobe` instead of `insmod`. You could just reboot the system, this isn't permanent.

Comment: It works. Do you have an Idea why?

Comment: No, not really. The strange thing is, that all of a sudden it started to do that, with no obvious reasons. Maybe the software isn't the problem, the hardware got stuck at some point, and then all that helps is to reload the module. This would explain, why a fresh install of Kubuntu didn't help eater. Only a reload did.

Comment: Very strange indeed, the fix is also permanent for me. A completely new kubuntu install/upgrade did not resolve the problem, however, unloading / reloading the kernel mod did. Fascinating.

Comment: Since a kernel update to 5.8 i never had the problem again...

Comment: Given it it now early 2024, this problem still occurs from time to time to me, easily fixed using this answer.

Comment: I had to search for my own answer because it happened for me also again. :D

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem until I updated the motherboard BIOS to 4201 using the file downloaded from the ROG website.
ROG-CROSSHAIR-VIII-HERO-WIFI-ASUS-4201.CAP
After rebooting and asserting the optimized defaults/rebooting, the problem was gone and Bluetooth mouse came right up like magic.